# tcltk error in R

Tags: r, x11

I'm receiving an error in R in that I cannot figure out. I've done a lot of searching online and from what I can tell, this is a common issue. However, I haven't been able to get any of the proposed solutions I've found to work for me.

Here's the error:

```
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
    call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
    error: unable to load shared object
    '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
    dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXft.2.dylib
    Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
    Reason: image not found
```

Can anyone explain in simplified language what this means and how to fix it?

My only guess is that it says its referencing "/usr/X11/" but from looking in the directories it seems like it should be going through "/opt/X11/" If that is the issue, I still haven't been able to figure out how to address it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It would help us understand the problem/solution if you told us when you encounter this error. Is it simply when opening RStudio, or is it after trying to load a specific library or to run a function? More details would help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had tried a similar symlink command before and it hadn't fixed it. The one in the Rcmdr question response seemed to work though. Thanks, I hadn't seen that particular question.